# Data Compression Enhancement in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Is there any specific enhancements in SQL Server 2012 for [Data Compression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280449.aspx) Feature?

Last time I checked SQL Server 2008 R2 introduced support for Unicode characters so columns with `NCHAR` data types (excepts CLOBS and BLOBS) can now take advantage of compression technology in SQL Server.

Comment: `"SQL 2008 R2 introduced support for Unicode characters"` -- what?

Comment: @JonSeigel Not sure if you were just pointing out that it is clumsily phrased but clearly talking about http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee240835.aspx

Comment: @Martin: I thought the statement meant that `n[var]char` columns could not be compressed in 2008, which didn't make sense. So 2008 R2 added *additional* compression on these column types, correct? I was unaware of that.

Comment: @JonSeigel Yes. Also normal row compression doesn't do anything to nvarchar/varchar but the unicode compression will apply there.

Comment: @JonSeigel -- Noted I should have phrased little better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were under-the-covers performance enhancements (nothing concrete, see for example [this book excerpt](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/databases/microsoft-sql-server/9781118106884/chapter-11-optimizing-sql-server-2012/toc81). Otherwise, no, 2008 R2 compression and 2012 compression are functionally equivalent.